# How can I scroll up screen when the keyboard is shown?

Tags: android, scroll, scrollview

I want to be able to scroll up the login screen when the keyboard is shown. I don't use ScrollView, I only have a RelativeLayout with an ImageView and another LinearLayout inside it. I've tried adding whats below in AndroidManifest but didn't work.

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
```

Comment: Do you want to scroll when the keyboard is shown or just that you want layout to scroll up when keyboard appears? Try "adjustPan" for second one.

Comment: i want my layout to be scrollable only when the keyboard is shown and in rest not scrollable

Comment: put whole thing in a scrollview and enable scrolling only when keyboard is active/available if you dont want it to be scrollable otherwise. All this things are doable, need some googling.

Answer (score 0):

Place your root-layout (the Relative layout in your case) inside a `scrollview` (let's say it's called scrollview1), and when the keyboard appears, run the following code:

```
scrollview1.post(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    scrollview1.fullScroll(View.FOCUS_UP);

                }
            });
```

Edit: Please note that scrollviews can have only one child, so make sure of that.

Comment: If I place my RelativeLayout inside a ScrollView it makes the layout longer and scrollable and I don't want that. I want the layout to be scrollable only when the keyboard is shown.

Comment: In this case keep your `relative layout` and use the methods `scrollTo()`  or  `scrollBy()` to achieve what you want.

Comment: Here are the links:   

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View#scrollBy(int,%20int)

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View#scrollTo(int,%20int)

Answer (score 0):

While adding activity in manifest add

```
<activity
            android:name=".Activities.InputsActivity"
            ...
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
            />
```